# $A_r$-singularities and effectiveness of some divisor.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X=\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x,y,t]\big/(xy-t^n))$ for some $n$. Let $Y\subset X$ be defined by the prime ideal $(y,t)$. If we know that $$K_X-mY$$
is effective, can we say something about the relation between $n$ and $m$?